# How to load Smooch in a fragment in Android

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment, smooch

I am using Smooch library to load an activity at the moment. The codebase is as below:

```
Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.botButton);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (isConnected()) {
                ConversationActivity.show(getActivity().getApplication(), Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            } else {
```

So mainly ConversationActivity.show will open a new Smooch activity. However, I cannot open it as  a fragment. The new smooch activity always covers the whole screen.

The link below is the Smooch library that I am using:

https://docs.smooch.io/guide/native-android-sdk/

Anyone knows how to do it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As of version 4.4.0, the only official way to use Smooch in a `Fragment` outside of `ConversationActivity` is by building your own `Fragment` and use `Smooch`'s core library.

You can [create an issue](https://github.com/smooch/smooch-android/issues) if you'd like to see this option in the future and we'll look into it.